# Laravel One to many

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel I'm making movies and series archive web application. I'm stuck in the category area and I want your help.  Let me tell you where I hang out. In the movie area, a movie can go into more than one category.  I want to show the films that are in this category on my movies page in a list. I have no idea how to do this too.I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create three tables
first one is

```
movies
```

with columns like this

```
id,movie_name,movie_director,movice_info ..ect
```

the id column sould be `primary int not null auto increment` 
the second table will be the

```
categorys
```

with columns like this

```
id,category_name,category_parent_id
```

now id is primary key and category_name is the name but category_parent_id is most of categories are tree nested so its gonna be the id of same table and its gonna be nullable
your categories table will looks like this

```
id           category_name                 category_id
1             comedies movies                null
2             actions comedies movies        1
3             drama comedies  movies         1
4             dramas movies                  null
5             sad drama movies               4
```

remember that you will put movies not inside parent categorys but inside shild categorys categorys have column category_id not null 
or you can create anther table called `category_ids` and put anther relation

and now the third table called

```
movie_categorys
```

this will have this columns

```
id,movie_category_movie_id,movie_category_category_id
```

lets say you have three movies 
with this data

```
id            movie name           ect data
1              first move             ect..
2              second movie           ect ..
```

and this categorys

```
id           category_name                 category_id
1             comedies movies                null
2             actions comedies movies        1
3             drama comedies  movies         1
4             dramas movies                  null
5             sad drama movies               4
```

and you want the first movie inside category `actions comedies movies` and category `sad drama movies`
you will put data inside `movie_categorys` like this

```
id        movie_category_movie_id  movie_category_category_id
number          1                        2
number          1                        5
```

and you want to put second movie with categorys `drama comedies  movies` and `sad drama movies` and `actions comedies movies`
your data will be like this

```
id        movie_category_movie_id  movie_category_category_id
number          2                        2
number          2                        3
number          2                        5
```

this is how you store data 
now lets talk about relations 
inside movie model usually its should be called like this

```
Movie
```

you have to write this relation

movies belongs to many categorys 
and category has many movies 
i hope this answer your question

Answer (score 0):

It is a Many to Many relationship. You need 3 tables:

```
movies
-id


category_movie
-movie_id
-category_id

categories
-id
```

In you Movie Model define de retaltionship

```
public function categories()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```